# How to have global $user variable in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: authentication, view, global, laravel-5, shared

### Context

> Laravel ships with two authentication controllers out of the box, which are located in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` namespace.
>
> ...
>
> You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade: `$user = Auth::user();`

Reference: [Laravel 5.2 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

I'm able to log in successfully and I'm redirected to the correct place as defined in the `AuthController.php`, but now I need access to the `$user` object in most of my views such as for checking the user's information, access priveleges, etc.

### Problem

How do I properly provide access to the `$user` variable on all of my views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How other people have been doing it

User [imJohnBen](https://laracasts.com/@imJohnBon) of Laracast asked [how a Laravel 5 service provider can be used to share view variables](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-service-provider-for-sharing-view-variables?page=1). He later shares how he was able to use the existing `ComposerServiceProvider` and added a `GlobalComposer` to be able to share variables on all the views.

I followed his answer but there was a missing step. I couldn't contribute to the Laracast forums, thus leading to the creation of this StackOverflow question.

The Laravel version I'm using here is Laravel `5.2.*`.

### Answer

1. Find the existing `ComposerServiceProvider` class. I found mine in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php`.
2. Import/reference the `ViewFactory` dependency at the top of the file.

   ```
   use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;
   ```
3. Add the `boot` method, or modify it if it exists already. Make sure the `ViewFactory` was injected (add it as a parameter in the boot function):

   ```
   /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
     {
         $view->composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\GlobalComposer');
     }
   ```
4. Make a `ViewComposers` folder in your `app/Http` folder.
5. Make a `GlobalComposer.php` file in the `ViewComposers` folder, containing the following:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

   use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   class GlobalComposer {

       /**
        * Bind data to the view.
        *
        * @param  View  $view
        * @return void
        */
       public function compose(View $view)
       {
           $view->with('user', Auth::user());
       }

   }
   ```
6. (The missing step) Finally, make sure everything is wired up by going to your `config/app.php` file and making sure that `ComposerServiceProvider` is in your providers list.

   ```
   'providers' = [
       /*
        * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
        */
       Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
       Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

       // etc...

       Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
   ]
   ```

Afterwards, the `$user` variable and any other variables you define in the `GlobalComposer` will be accessible in any of the views you render.